# How to code a JavaScript modal popup (to replace Ajax)?

Tags: javascript, modalpopups

I need to replace our [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) Modal Popup controls with a JavaScript equivalent. We use this as a simple context sensitive help type popup. I did a quick browse but didn't see quite what I was looking for. I just need some text and a simple Close button/link, but I would like the page darkened below the popup, as it does with the Ajax modal control.

Can anyone suggest a nice JavaScript popup/help type solution that you've used?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can provide you the code.  Do your modifications as necessary, OK?

Page JavaScript:

```
function myPop() { 
    this.square = null;
    this.overdiv = null;

    this.popOut = function(msgtxt) {
        //filter:alpha(opacity=25);-moz-opacity:.25;opacity:.25;
        this.overdiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.overdiv.className = "overdiv";

        this.square = document.createElement("div");
        this.square.className = "square";
        this.square.Code = this;
        var msg = document.createElement("div");
        msg.className = "msg";
        msg.innerHTML = msgtxt;
        this.square.appendChild(msg);
        var closebtn = document.createElement("button");
        closebtn.onclick = function() {
            this.parentNode.Code.popIn();
        }
        closebtn.innerHTML = "Close";
        this.square.appendChild(closebtn);

        document.body.appendChild(this.overdiv);
        document.body.appendChild(this.square);
    }
    this.popIn = function() {
        if (this.square != null) {
            document.body.removeChild(this.square);
            this.square = null;
        }
        if (this.overdiv != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(this.overdiv);
        this.overdiv = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Now the HTML page, using the JavaScript file:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="NAME OF THE PAGE!.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.overdiv { filter: alpha(opacity=75);
                      -moz-opacity: .75;
                      opacity: .75;
                      background-color: #c0c0c0;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 0px;
                      left: 0px;
                      width: 100%; height: 100%; }

        div.square { position: absolute;
                     top: 200px;
                     left: 200px;
                     background-color: Menu;
                     border: #f9f9f9;
                     height: 200px;
                     width: 300px; }
        div.square div.msg { color: #3e6bc2;
                             font-size: 15px;
                             padding: 15px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 300px;
                padding: 20px; margin: 20px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pop = new myPop();
        pop.popOut("Jose leal");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that this can help.

Answer (score 7):

I've used the simplemodal jQuery plugin and I've been quite happy with it. You can check it out [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.dialog)? [ui.jquery.com]

It's the simplest one, and can come bundled with a lot of other eye candy. Of course you could also look around the rest of the [jQuery plug-ins page](http://plugins.jquery.com/), specially the [Windows and Overlays section](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/43).

Answer (score 0):

I developed a javascript library called [Msg](https://madprops.github.io/Msg/). It allows to easily create a modal window / popup. It creates an overlay behind it that darkens the background. It has no close button but it can be closed by clicking the background overlay.