# javascript modal pop without jquery

Tags: javascript, modalpopup

Is there a way to create a purely javascript (not jquery) modal pop-up.  Does anyone know of a library where I can say Modal_ask (option1,option2,option3,...)  and it stops the javascript processing until a value is returned.

Similar to confirm, but with variable number of options.

Thx

R

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just an FYI, you might want to [read through the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding what types of questions are a good fit for the site, as [Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562).

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug for my vanilla JS modal pop-up script: https://github.com/cferdinandi/modals