# How can change a styling of javascript alert button?

Tags: javascript, styles, alert

I want to change a style of javascript alert box.As you can see in many website like
facebook,Here is alert boxex are stlyed.how can I do that.

Comment: i dont believe you can change the native `window.alert()` style. it must've been a custom `<div>` you were seeing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it; it is implemented by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't style the alert box.**

You can create a div put the message in it style it with css and pop it up with  javascript.

An example for this can be find in the jQuery UI dialog widget, [**DEMO**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You can not style alert box, what you could do is create a modal popup

eg.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

http://defunkt.io/facebox/

[How to code a JavaScript modal popup (to replace Ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax)