# Designing/Styles of Javascript Popup Box?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can change a styling of javascript alert button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997944/how-can-change-a-styling-of-javascript-alert-button)

Just wondering if there is any way to style popup boxes?

**"UPDATE"**

This is the actual code which is creating alerts. If I use jQuery dialog then what will be form of the code? I mean How jQuery's code will be inserted with this code?
Thanks

```
<?php 
// Start YOURLS engine
require_once( '../y/includes/load-yourls.php' );

function selfURL() { $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s; $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]); return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; } function strleft($s1, $s2) { return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); }
?>

    <?php
    // Part to be executed if FORM has been submitted
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['url']) ) {
        $url     = yourls_sanitize_url( $_REQUEST['url'] );
        $return  = yourls_add_new_link( $url );     
        $shorturl = isset( $return['shorturl'] ) ? $return['shorturl'] : '';        
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$shorturl')</script>";

    // Part to be executed when no form has been submitted
    }   
        $site = YOURLS_SITE;
        $var = selfURL();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by "popup box", you mean the native dialogs generated by `alert()`, `confirm()` and similar — no, there isn't.

If the appearance of them is that important, then you will need to generate DOM elements, bind event handlers to replicate the functionality of the buttons, and style them instead.

Comment: I'm using 

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$shorturl')</script>";

this in php, can I use jQuery here for echo?
Thanks

Comment: @Taimoor — Not in any way that begins to resemble "something sane".

Comment: Any suggestions how I can use jQuery?

Comment: You can [manipulate the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) with it. (Still not a replacement for PHP's `echo` though).

Comment: Actually I just wanted to make that text selectable which appears in the popup. In alert() its not possible for IE users. So, that's the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `alert`, `prompt` or something else which is built-in - no you cant set them a custom styles, they use the default browser style.

If you want a custom style you need JavaScript window plugin. Some UI libraries which provides window widgets are jQuery UI, jQWidgets, Kendo UI, Sencha, etc...

Here are few examples:

**jqxWindow by jQWidgets**

[image]

**jQuery UI dialog**

[image]

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please explain me how can I use jQuery Dialog with that code? Thank you!

Comment: Here is a usage demo http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a confusion about how to use its code for displaying $shorturl which is now appearing as alert()