# Choose language popup on page load

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup, multilingual

I am building a multilingual site and I want to insert a function, on initial page load, that finds the default language setting of the browser and then prompts the user to choose which language they would like. (Eng/Esp)

Of course the language in the prompt would be in the same language of the browser. I already have navigation between these languages on all pages page but I want to intercept the user upon entrance and avoid using a splash page.

Can anybody advise me on how this is done?

Comment: Insert call to popup function in `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: @Deadlock Hello, thank you, but my knowledge of JS is still very limited. I only understand basic console.log, return, print, etc. Could you explain a little more or perhaps you know a link?

Comment: @Deadlock I don't see a jQuery tag.

Comment: `$` is a shortcut for `jquery` @Bondye

Comment: @Deadlock Lol I know that. But your comment you say he has to use jQuery for this, but the OP don't have the jquery [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) bounded on the question...

Comment: Oh okay got your point :) @Bondye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a custom event listener

```
function addEvent(to, type, fn) {
    // Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera
    if(document.addEventListener) {
        to.addEventListener(type, fn, false)
    }
    // Microsoft ActiveX Scripts
    else if(document.attachEvent) {  
        to.attachEvent('on'+type, fn)
    }
    // Last hope
    else {  
        to['on'+type] = fn
    }
}
```

Add event listener on the window when its loaded and run the function `onDomLoaded()`

```
addEvent(window, 'load', onDomLoaded)
```

Create the function onDomLoaded

```
function onDomLoaded() {
    alert('Im finished loading the entire window, your language is: ' + navigator.language)

}
```

Here the [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zexzp/1/)

Comment: Thats amazing! And then I would add something within the final function to choose between. Make another function outside of it and then call it within?

Comment: Can be done both. Use the `onDomLoaded` function as the `init`/`document class`/`constructor` of your javascript. Be creative :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Deadlock has said you can use a JavaScript Modal pop-up. Someone has given an example of this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289028/1218040).

You can create this pop-up containing buttons to select the language.

Comment: Thank you that looks like it may be really useful. Would the method be to replace the *null* terms for the address of the page?

Comment: Not too sure havent looked into too much. If you just google javascript or jquery modal pop. There are pre-built bits of code you can use that are simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on how to get the browser language using [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199760/how-to-get-the-browser-language-using-java-script). And as you specified PHP in your question tags, answer to do so with [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php).

Comment: This is great I might use the second comment on the PHP page becuase it seems very easy to implement. Thank you