# Open php page in modal popup window on pure javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, modal-dialog

I need a **modal** popup (so i shouldn't have additional tab in browser and parent page should be blocked (and darkened) till popup is open) in javascript. Can it be done without css overlay (as i have some dynamic data - so it should be javascript) and without using additional libraries like jQuery (as i don't want to use it for the sake of only one task)?

Also pop up should contain php script output

HTML:

```html
<div onclick="show(789);">Edit task #789</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
function show(id) {
    //need open link like "/edit_single_task.php?id=789" in modal popup
    }
```

**EDIT**

Thanks, [How to code a JavaScript modal popup (to replace Ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax) works fine for me. But how can i combine it with php script output?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax

Comment: Missing your draft code

Comment: You'd want to use an <iframe>.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?  Its pure javascript like you requested.

http://jsmodal.com/index.php

Comment: "without using additional libraries"