# javascript pop up a div element in the center of the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, popup

How could I pop up a div element in the center of the webpage.
also .I need a button on the div to close the div element.
and the div element will not affect the webpage at all.

In my JS code, I already have a div element created.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.background = "white";
div.id = "demo";
$(div).addClass("GridTableContent");
```

I want to pop up the div element I created in the center of my webpage.
and add a close the div button.

**Update**

I Think I need to provide more detail about the problem

First,this code are injected into a webpage in a chrome extension so it's pure javascript

surely I can't write this

```
<div class='overlay'>
<div class='popup'>
<div class='close'>&#10006;</div>
   <h2>Popup</h2>
</div>
```

It'a all created dynamically,so I guess I can't use the code provided below.
I see other question before ,someone suggest me to use 
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

and I find the BASIC MODAL DIALOG in that page is good ,
Is there any way to use that .

**Update**

I find I need to give the more detailed information.

At first I create a button and already injected into a webpage

```
var div = document.getElementById("btnSearch");
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.id='visualization';
input.type='button';
input.value='visualiztion';
$(input).insertAfter(div);
```

Then I create a div element

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.background = "white";
div.id = "demo";
```

How can I do this,when I'm click the button then the div element popup at the webpage in the center.also I guess I need to create a button to close the div element.

Comment: post sample code here.

Comment: haven't tried,but JQuery is available to me.So i need some suggestion about what should I do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax, check that question

Comment: Regarding whatever you've shared after the edit- What is the actual HTML structure? how are you planning to see this div..? it doesn't have a height, width etc. so it'll not be visible. where is the respective css..? can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

HTML

```
<div class='overlay'>
<div class='popup'>
    <div class='close'>&#10006;</div>
     <h2>Popup</h2>
</div>
```

Show

CSS

```
*{
 margin:0;
}
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
.overlay {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 z-index:9999;
}
.close {
 position:absolute;
 top:-40px;
 right:-5px;
 z-index:99;
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
}
.popup {
 position:absolute;
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 top:25%;
 left:25%;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background:white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px black;
}
.popup h2 {
 font-size:15px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 color:#fff;
 background:rgb(24, 108, 209);
 border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.button {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bolder;
 border-radius:10px;
 background:silver;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.button').click(function () {
  $('.overlay').show();
})
$('.close').click(function () {
  $('.overlay').hide();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/s2N4Z/)

**Update**

Dynamic injection:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/s2N4Z/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need all the code created by javascript. include the button and the poped up div element.

Comment: Thank you,it works,However, $('body').html(htmlString) seems to overwrite the whole webpage. and var htmlString="<div class='overlay'>"
    +"<div class='popup'>"
        +"<div class='close'>&#10006;</div>"
         +"<h2>Popup</h2>"
    +"</div>"
 +"</div>"
    +"<button class='button'>Show</button>" still have not include my div element create dynamiclly, how can I add the div into  that ?

Comment: instead of replacing the html with `html()`, use `append()`. What div element? you can change the div having `class=popup` in htmlstring to have the id or classes you need ..

Comment: I change my problem a little bit so it's more clear.Thanks for your attension

Comment: @user3587729 when you're modifying the question, mention that it's an update for better understanding and keep the original question. Otherwise the existing comments and answers will confuse future readers, hence i'm reverting your question back to the initial state with the updates. now edit and modify as you wish, without changing the entire question