# change background color with ui-dialog-background transparent dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Good day,

I am really stuck here.  I have a working transparent background, thanks to this blog: http://tqclarkson.com/2012/04/19/transparent-jquery-mobile-dialogs/

But no matter what I try I just cannot make the transparent background different color.  I need the background color of the parent content to be black and transparent when dialog pops up.  So far I have this, as per the blog:

```
.ui-dialog-background {
opacity: 0.5;
display: block !important;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.ui-dialog-background.pop.in {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.ui-dialog {
min-height: 100% !important;
background: transparent !important;
}
```

And JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagebeforeshow', function(e, ui) {
    ui.prevPage.addClass("ui-dialog-background ");
   });

$('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagehide', function(e, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-background ").removeClass("ui-dialog-background ");
   });
});
```

I tried various different approaches, but none of them work.  Is there any way to make the transparent background to be darker color?

Thank you kindly,
Victor.

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer might address what you're trying to do: [How to code a JavaScript modal popup (to replace Ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/how-to-code-a-javascript-modal-popup-to-replace-ajax)

I've used this approach and it works well to "grey out" the background while the modal is visible.  You should be able to alter the color and/or opacity to suit your needs.

Comment: Any other suggestions?